# What does "dirty" mean in relation to a drink?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I saw in a [movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1283887/) a girl asking for a "very dirty" drink. Did she want higher alcohol content?

I searched [definitions](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=dirty&tbs=dfn:1) of *dirty* but I couldn't find any related to a drink.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is [an explanation with some examples](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-dirty-mojito.htm):

> To make a drink “dirty,” means you may slightly change the color and taste by adding or changing some of the essential ingredients. A dirty martini for instance contains olive juice. There are actually several versions of the dirty mojito. One classic is to use raw sugar instead of white granulated. This gives the drink a very slightly tan or “dirty” color.

Answer (score 11):

A martini is simply gin (or vodka) with some proportion of vermouth (the relative proportion determines whether it is "dry" - almost purely gin or vodka - or "wet" - more vermouth.)
It can be garnished with an olive or a lemon twist.

If you garnish with an olive, and then add a bit of the brine from the olive jar to the drink, that is a "dirty martini."  A "very dirty" martini would, I'm guessing, contain a lot of brine.

Answer (score 4):

The above descriptions of a dirty alcoholic beverage are excellent. I believe that these two answers however may have ignored the context in which this phrase was used.

This is only my personal opinion, but I think that this character was making a double entendre, implying that she not only wanted a dirty drink, but she was receptive to vigorous sexual intercourse.

Once again this is just a guess, but the context in which this phrase was used may shed more light.

Comment: Or she might have been implying that she's into watersports?

Answer (score 3):

In England we use the phrase 'Dirty Pint' to describe a pint made up of 3, or more, different alcoholic drinks. Dirty pints are usually consumed for reasons such as being crap at cards or if it is your birthday. 
In some drinking games there will be an empty pint glass in the middle of the table, to which everyone may contribute a bit of their own personal drink, until the glass is full and there is a dirty pint. The loser of the game will have to consume this delicious beverage.

In the context of Jader's observation, I imagine that this girl wanted to get very drunk!

Answer (score 2):

dirty, in the sense of "dirty martini" is taking the water from the canned olives, and pouring some inside the drink, giving it a "murky" look.

Answer (score -3):

Dirty, with respect to a drink, means that the olive for garnish is stuffed with a blue cheese.

Comment: that not what any sources I've read tell me.

Comment: Can you cite a source for this, please?